# Circular dependencies in flex libraries

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, circular-dependency

I have two Flex libraries that reference each other. Both use link type "`External`", and I manually load then with the Loader class.

I'm getting the error "`A cycle was detected in the build path of project: foo`".

Is there any way to resolve this? Maybe a parameter for the compiler or something.

I don't think there should be a problem, since with the `external` link type the source code doesn't get compiled into the library...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds more like you need to rethink your code.

Maybe you can eleminate dependency one way by using interfaces?

If you could give an overview of the dependencies maybe I or someone else could give ideas on how to redesign the structure.

**Edit:**

How nice of you to give me a minus... Let me quote the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) on the subject:

> [...] in software design circular
>   dependencies between larger software
>   modules are considered an
>   **anti-pattern** because of their **negative effects**.
>
> [...]
>
> Circular dependencies can cause many
>   unwanted effects in software programs.
>   Most problematic from a software
>   design point of view is the tight
>   coupling of the mutually dependent
>   modules which reduces or **makes
>   impossible the separate re-use of a
>   single module**.
>
> Circular dependencies can cause a
>   domino effect when a small local
>   change in one module spreads into
>   other modules and has unwanted global
>   effects (program errors, compile
>   errors). Circular dependencies can
>   also result in infinite recursions or
>   other unexpected failures.
>
> Circular dependencies may also cause
>   memory leaks by preventing certain
>   very primitive automatic garbage
>   collectors (those that use reference
>   counting) from deallocating unused
>   objects.
>
> [...]
>
> Circular dependencies are often
>   **introduced by inexperienced programmers** who need to implement
>   some kind of callback functionality.
>   Experienced programmers avoid such
>   unnecessary circular dependencies by
>   applying design patterns like the
>   observer pattern.

*(Emphasis added)*

But then again, maybe you are smarter than the collective that writes on wikipedia...

Comment: +1 External Flex libraries that reference each other is a bad idea. A practical way around this is to amalgamate the libraries, and extract common dependencies to a second library, but still, defeats the purpose of re-usable libraries.